# libGDX - Black buttons and text after changing screen

Tags: java, libgdx

I've recently discovered a strange problem in my libGDX program. When I start my program I first show a `SplashScreen`, then the `MainMenu` screen, and then you can enter the program. The problem is, that if I change `screen` while I'm on the main menu, all of my `TextButton`s become completely black, and their text characters become black boxes.
[image: Before changing screen]

[image: After changing screen]

(I reloaded the MainMenu using the splash button)

This affects all TextBoxes in all other screens. My thoughts is that my JSON is faulty, in some way. Because when I stop using drawables from my JSON and instead use `FreeTypeFont` instead of my `BitmapFont`, at least the font no longer turns black. I've used validators and they say there's no problem with my JSON, but here it is anyways (`TextButtonStyle` at the bottom):

```
{
"com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color": {
    "white": {
        "r": 1,
        "g": 1,
        "b": 1,
        "a": 1
    },

    "black": {
        "r": 0,
        "g": 0,
        "b": 0,
        "a": 1
    },

    "red": {
        "r": 1,
        "g": 0,
        "b": 0,
        "a": 1
    },

    "green": {
        "r": 0,
        "g": 1,
        "b": 0,
        "a": 1
    },

    "blue": {
        "r": 0,
        "g": 0,
        "b": 1,
        "a": 1
    },

    "dark_grey": {
        "r": 0.8,
        "g": 0.8,
        "b": 0.8,
        "a": 1
    }
},

"com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont": {
    "white": {
        "file": "data/fonts/white.fnt"
    },

    "black": {
        "file": "data/fonts/black.fnt"
    }
},

"com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle": {
    "default": {
        "titleFont": "black",
        "titleFontColor": "dark_grey"
    }
},

"com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle": {
    "default": {
        "font": "white", 
        "fontColor": "white"
    }
},

"com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List$ListStyle": {
    "default": {
        "font": "white",
        "fontColorUnselected": "white",
        "fontColorSelected": "black",
        "selection": "default.selection"
    }
},

"com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane$ScrollPaneStyle": {
    "default": {
        "hScrollKnob": "button.up",
        "vScrollKnob": "button.up"
    }
},

"com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle": {
    "default": {
        "up": "button.up",
        "down": "button.down",
        "font": "black",
        "pressedOffsetX": 1,
        "pressedOffsetY": -1
    }
}
}
```

Here's the code where I add and change the buttons' styles.

```
    // Splash Screen button
    buttonSplash = new TextButton("SPLASH SCREEN", skin);
    buttonSplash.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            // When you click the button, create a new screen
            ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new SplashScreen());
        }
    });
    buttonSplash.pad(20);
    //Rest of the buttons....
```

If you feel like you need the entire code I can post that as well, but it's fairly long which is why I refrained from posting it.

INSTANT EDIT: Tried with entirely new JSON (the one that comes with libGDX) and I still have the same problem.

Comment: Are you using a static `AssetManager`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem came from disposing the `skin`. I use a `static Skin` object in an external class as my skin, which is used by all classes that need that skin. My problem was that I disposed the skin in one of the screens, which disposed the skin that all other classes were using as well. I solved this by simply creating a `dispose();` method in the class that holds all of my skins, and dispose of them when I exit the game instead.

Comment: you are either disposing at the wrong time or you should reload and reinitialize the skin

Comment: You should not answer your own question when you did not entirely solved it. Change your initial question to include your update or add a comment (you can comment from 10 reputation I think).

Comment: I actually completely solved it about an hour later but forgot to edit my answer, but thanks for the insight.